# Boundary (singular) fit in lmer

Tags: r, statistics, regression, lme4, singular

I know this error has already been issued in stackoverflow, but the solution for the other questions doesn't seem to apply to my problem.
I have a very simple model that predicts energy expenditure based on the number of days.

```
a<-lmer(energy ~ days + (1|PCBType), data = stp_summary_v1 )
```

and the model gives the warning:

```
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

I cannot share the data, but here is the distribution:
[image]

What I've already tried without success:

- `a<-lmer(log(energy) ~ days + (1|PCBType), data = stp_summary_v1)`
- `a<-lmer(scale(energy) ~ days + (1|PCBType), data = stp_summary_v1)`
- `a<-lmer(log(energy) ~ log(days) + (1|PCBType), data = stp_summary_v1)`
- add more independent variables
- change `glmer()` family
- change the independent variable

Any idea why I keep getting this warning?

Comment: Do you only have two values of `PCBType`? If so, it is probably worth adding it as a fixed effect

Comment: Yes, I only have to values, but initially I had 4 (2 of them with only two levels, so I removed the observations, as I thought that was the issue). I'm not interest in this effect, I just want to control for the variable...

Comment: If you want to control for it, you could add as a fixed effect & possibly look at an interaction with days? (Two groups is not really enough to get an estimate of the variance between them - [answers and links therein](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37647/what-is-the-minimum-recommended-number-of-groups-for-a-random-effects-factor))

Comment: What if you run `a<-lm(energy ~ days + PCBType, data = stp_summary_v1 )` do you still have issues? Also, is `days` a continuous variable? Sometimes having what should be a continuous variable that gets read-in as a factor can cause some problems.. but it is difficult to help without some data.. otherwise we are just blindly guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only two levels of `PCBType`, this variable should be a fixed effect.

By specifying it as random you are asking the software to estimate a variance for a normally distributed variable from only 2 observations, which of course does not make any sense and is almost certainly the cause of the singular fit.